# Nginx Reverse Proxy 301 Redirects

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up an nginx proxy in a way I'm not sure will work... Basically, I have 3 servers running. Server A is an nginx reversed proxy. Server B and C are backend servers. When a client requests http://domain.com/file.jpg, it hits Server A than passes the request back to Server B. The file could be on server B or C. If server B doesn't have the file, it sends a 301 redirect to the file on Server C. The problem with this is the 301 goes back to the browser and changes the URL in the client.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the 301 stay internal. Nginx would see and follow the 301 to the correct file location on Server C, but the client wouldn't know the difference. The client shouldn't be able to tell whether the file is on B or C, or even know the addresses of them...

Thanks!

Comment: You could catch 301 redirect with `error_page` directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using proxy_next_upstream for that.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Answer (score -1):

Using upstream to setup load balancing for reverse proxy, it fill auto fetch data from 2 backend server.

Comment: even if the data only exists on one of the two backend servers?

Comment: using location and check request before direct to upstream

Comment: You can't use location to check request beforehand. There are tens of millions of files. There's no way to tell ahead of time which server the file resides on.